# Session ends without a reason

Tags: php, session

I have a website that allows users to log in. Now the problem is, that the session ends if another page (session is started there too, so users should stay logged in) is opened. Its strange because sometimes it works as intended and sometimes it fails.
For security reasons I use session_regenerate_id(true). Is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry but no code no answer. Give us somethin to work on.

Comment: write some code so we may help you .......

Comment: how do you know session ends?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `session_regenerate_id`, PHP registers a new session. Basically you are intentionally starting a new session and then asking why a new session is started :)

Only do a session_regenerate_id when you actually plan to start a new session.

Comment: It should not delete session information but delete the old session file. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: Yep. Your current session gets a new ID and your data is stored under that id. It will not however, send a new cookie. So the next session_start will open the old session without data. ..

Answer (score 0):

Check the Path for your Session Cookie or check whether there exists two different Session Cookies for your domain.